# Fate of black holes in an accelerating expanding universe

Tags: black-holes, acceleration, space-expansion

If matter within the event horizon of a black hole continues to fall towards the singularity, won't there be a distant time in the future when the accelerating expansion of space is fast enough that even the super-close falling matter begins distancing from each other, "going outward"?